# Add a date range with calendar pop-up using Search API, Facet and Drupal 8

Tags: php, filter, drupal-8, facet, faceted-search

I am using the search API to content on the search index. 
I need to filter that content by a date range as well as other filters using the facet module.

The problem is that I haven't been able to find a way to expose the Start date and End Date fields so the client can select from the calendar pop-up the date range they want to filter by.

I found the slider date range module but I just need a simple calendar pop-up with the facet module.

I have tried the Slider date range with facets but it doesn't adapt to what I need to build.

Answer (score 0):

I Found the solution!

Using Views filters, I exposed the date filter and then with the [Better Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) module, went to the field settings and then select jQuery UI Datepicker.

In that way, I was able to display a filter with a pop-up calendar/datepicker.

Comment: Thanks for reporting back with your solution. So this is not a facets-based solution, right?

Comment: Nope, I had to expose the date filters from views in order to expose the calendar pop-up.